# Unable to match multiple ip addresses using grep

Tags: text-processing, grep

I am trying to match multiple ip addresses, 100.x..x.x and 13.19.x.x

here is my syntax.

```
for item in `cat s3`
do
egrep -o '100\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\} | 13\.19\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' $item
done
```

I am reading IPs from file `s3` and then trying to match multiple IP address pattern. I don't know what is going wrong. Is the syntax for egrep correct?

Comment: We don't know either since you haven't shown us what you are trying to parse. Please [edit] your question and i) show us an example of `s3` and ii) show us your desired output.

Comment: at first glance, the space characters around the `|` are likely to be a problem.  depends on the input file.

Comment: `grep -o '1\(00\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\|3\.19\)\(\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\)\{2\}' s3`

Comment: Implicit in the last comment - you're currently asking `grep` to search a file called `$item` repeatedly, for each value `$item` takes. You can give the original file directly to `grep` and avoid the loop. If you need to extract entries from the file in that way, edit in more detail of the problem.

Comment: @MichaelHomer I have tried what you just mentioned above.

Comment: @Costas i tried with your piece of code. I don't see any results nor error. The terminal returns just $ prompt.

Comment: @SwateshPakhare Code is tested. Please check would you use *grep* or ***e**grep*?

Comment: @Costas i got it man. I was using minus sign instead of hyphen. Thank you mate.